# Get channel by id in discord interactions

Tags: python, discord.py, discord-interactions

I would like to send logs messages in a logs channel, but for that I need the logs channel object.

Because I used discord interactions to define my bot, I can't use the `get_channel(id)` method. I can't find the method to get a channel by id in the [discord-interactions documentation](https://discord-interactions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

Thanks in advance.

```
bot = interactions.Client(
    token = my_token,
    intents = interactions.Intents.ALL
    )

logs_channel = bot.get_channel(channel_id = 1015371164312424468)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[...]", line 17, in <module>
    logs_channel = bot.get_channel(channel_id = 1015371164312424468)
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'get_channel'
```

Comment: Have u tried `fetch_channel()` ?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `discord-interactions` and not just `discord.py`? Interactions are part of v2.X which is on PyPi.

Comment: ConnerWolf08 : I just tried and it doesn't work, but I think it's because @stijndcl is right.
I'll rewrite my code tomorrow and post an update.
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```py
logs_channel = await interactions.get(bot, interactions.Channel, object_id=your_channel_id)
```

To get the channel.

You can also join the support server as you would receive help faster